Why does my database not update the value of a column when I update it second time? SQL Alchemy and PostgreSQL
Hello I am new to Back end Programming and This is the back end of my very first Full Stack Application. I have a very basic Database which is basically just one table of Todolist which has three columns, id, task and is_complete. So when I update the value of is_complete for a specific id, it works for the first time, but if i try updating again then it does not work. I want it to turn true when my checkbox(in front-end) is clicked and to turn back to false if its clicked again. I have tried updating multiple time directly from SQL in pgAdmin and it works, the only time it doesnt work is through the SWAGGER UI and I dont know of anyother way to find out the error like in Javascript you can use the console.log to print stuff to see whats happening with the data at times, here I dont know how can I track data. Btw When I run the code. It  doesnt show any error and in SWAGGER UI its a successful response but in the database the column doesnt update. This is my main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from schemas import TodoSchemas
import models
from dbconnection import engine, get_db
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import crud

app = FastAPI()
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",  # Add your React development server URL
    "http://localhost:5173",  # Add any other relevant URLs
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"Data": "Working!"}
@app.get("/allToDoList/", response_model=list[TodoSchemas.TodoList])
def read_todolist(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    todoList = crud.getAllTasks(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return todoList

@app.post("/todo", tags=["todos"])
def createTodo(todo:TodoSchemas.TodoListBase,db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.createNewTask(todo=todo,db=db)

@app.put("/todo/{id}", tags=["todos"])
def update_todo(id: int, db:Session=Depends(get_db)) -> bool:
    return crud.updateTask(db=db,idToUpdate=id)

@app.delete("/todo/{id}", tags=["todos"])
def delete_todo(id: int, db:Session=Depends(get_db)) -> dict:
    return crud.deleteTask(db=db,idToDelete=id)

#This is crud.py:
def getAllTasks(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.TodoList).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()

def createNewTask(todo:TodoSchemas.TodoListBase,db: Session):
    db_task = models.TodoList(task=todo.task)
    db.add(db_task)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_task)
    return db_task

#THIS IS THE FUNCTION WITH THE PROBLEM:

def updateTask(db:Session, idToUpdate:int):
    todo = db.query(models.TodoList).filter_by(id=idToUpdate).first()
    if todo:
        try:
            todo.is_complete= not todo.is_complete
            # Your database operation
            db.commit()
            db.refresh(todo)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            db.rollback()  # Roll back in case of error
            return False
    else:
        print(f"No todo item found with id {idToUpdate}.")
        return False

def deleteTask(idToDelete:int,db:Session):
    id=db.query(models.TodoList).filter_by(id=idToDelete).delete()
    if id>0:
        db.commit()
        return {
            "message": f"{id} Task with ID {idToDelete} deleted successfully"
        }
    else:
        return {"message": f"Id: {idToDelete} was not found in the list "
#and this is models.py:
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Integer, String
from dbconnection import Base
class TodoList(Base):
    __tablename__ = "todolists"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    task = Column(String)
    is_complete = Column(Boolean)

#if for any reason you need to see shema,heres TodoSchemas.py:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
class TodoListBase(BaseModel):
    task:str
class TodoList(TodoListBase):
        id: int
        is_complete: bool
        class Config:
            from_attributes=True

My database is in pgAdmin using render.
This is might be something that is related to the problem because I cannot think of any other issue:
File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 78, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 62, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\annas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()

This shows before almost every Application Startup Complete in console

Is the swagger UI showing you just true or false as the result?

For troubleshooting  1) Add print(todo.is_complete) after todo.is_complete= not todo.is_complete 2) Look at the Postgres log and see what is hitting the database.

I updated pgadmin 4 which was version 2 or 4 to 8, also updated python and restarted everything and now its working...... but i would like to know how do you check postgres log? I couldnt find the problem bcz i could not find any way of seeing any print() results anywhere in Swagger ui or the path or even the console.

yes ui only shows true or false bcz i have made the function return boolean value

updateTask returns True if it succeeds, False if it does not.  It  does not return the value of is_complete. You probably want to return a response model from the route.
